# SharePoint error Report Server has encountered

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I am trying to configure SSRS 2008 R2 using SharePoint Integration mode on SharePoint 2010 server, I have followed some blogs including MSDN to configure SSRS in Integrated mode.

But once I click on Web Service URL on "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" after performing all the required steps of configuration.  it gives me above below error.

Reporting Services Error

> Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error. (rsSharePointError)
>   Get Online Help The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070003)

**As well as "Reporting Services Integration" is not showing in Central Admin > General Settings**

Following are the details in error log.

> -------Details-------- System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: This operation is not
>   supported on a report server that is configured to run in SharePoint
>   integrated mode. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.OperationNotSupportedSharePointModeException:
>   This operation is not supported on a report server that is configured
>   to run in SharePoint integrated mode.    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.GetProperties(String
>   Item, Property[] Properties, Property[]& Values)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.GetProperties(String
>   ItemPath, Property[] Properties, Property[]& Values)

Answer (score 0):

This is as expected, as per this blog post, SSRS in sharepoint mode is not designed to be accessed by its endpoints directly.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5f42c2f4-1164-471b-854c-b57b7bd83b0b/report-manager-url-httpservernamereports-is-not-working-in-sharepoint-integrated-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices

If you don't see the section in Central Admin, try activating the Report Server feature:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677366(v=sql.105).aspx
(linked from this article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677365(v=sql.105).aspx)

"Click General Application Settings. You should see a section named Reporting Services. This section has links to pages used to specify integration settings. If you do not see this section, you must activate the report server integration feature. For more information, see How to: Activate the Report Server Feature in Site Settings."

Comment: Bro, I have a issue with Report Server URL not Report Manager URL...

Comment: Dear All, 

SSRS is successfully configured.

Reporting Services Integration is now showing in Central Admin > General Settings and Report Server Integration Feature available under site collection feature.

The above issue has fixed:

Install the Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint and then re RUN configuration wizard.

But Report Server Web URL still showing same error message "The system cannot find the path specified"